# Where to add hooks in a class

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

In the code below, shouldn't the hooks under the bottom two functions be placed inside the constructor?

```
class The_Class {
    private static $instance = null;

    public static function get_instance() {
        return null == self::$instance ? self::$instance = new self : self::$instance;
    }

    function __construct() {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', array( &$this, 'edit_nav_menu_walker' ) );
            add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', array( &$this, 'option' ), 12, 2 );
            add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', array( &$this, 'update_option_text' ), 10, 3 );
            add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', array( &$this, 'update_option_hide_show' ), 10, 3 );
            add_action( 'delete_post', array( &$this, 'remove_visibility_meta' ), 1, 3 );
        } else {
            add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', array( &$this, 'set_visibility' ), 10, 3 );
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'clear_gantry_menu_cache' ) );
        }
    }

    function deactivate_other_lsmi() {
        if ( is_plugin_active( 'lsmi-by-city/LSMI_City.php' ) ) {
            deactivate_plugins( 'lsmi-by-city/LSMI_City.php' );
        }
    }

add_action( 'admin_init', array( &$this, 'deactivate_other_lsmi' ) );

    function lsmi_load_admin_script() {
        wp_register_style( 'chosencss', plugins_url( 'assets/chosen.css', __FILE__ ), true, '', 'all' );
        wp_register_script( 'chosenjs', plugins_url( 'assets/chosen.jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chosencss' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chosenjs' );
    }

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'lsmi_load_admin_script' ) );

}
```

Comment: Seems that way.

Comment: I thought so too. But another well-reputed user told me to do it like this.

Comment: It is my personal preference to put any WordPress hooks into the `_construct` of a `Class`. Having them strewn throughout the object is acceptable, but just a bit messier from an `OOP` viewpoint.

Comment: Elaborate answer to follow.

Comment: Here are some excellent references, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70055/31545 and  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12383/31545 and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210928/31545

Comment: @NathanPowell Constructors are never meant to do any work. Adding actions and filters in a constructor is **wrong**. Check my links in the previous comment

Comment: Thanks for the reference @PieterGoosen. I specifically thought to elaborate on the fact that "Constructors are never meant to do any work". You saved me a lot of writing. I would also like to see (@)j8d Questions' code a bit cleaner to elaborate further.

Comment: I am not convinced that "Adding actions and filters in a constructor is wrong.". I also do not agree with the third link specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where to add hooks in a class?

"In class-based object-oriented programming, a constructor (abbreviation: ctor) is a special type of subroutine called to create an object. It prepares the new object for use, often accepting arguments that the constructor uses to set required member variables." Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)).

The constructor is not the place to add actions and filters.

> In the code below, shouldn't the hooks under the bottom two functions be placed inside the constructor?

The above code is invalid and will throw an error when you try to run it. The hooks under the bottom two functions need to be placed in a method, but not necessarily the constructor.

There are many things that I would change with the above code.

Firstly, what is the one thing this class does? Impossible to answer since it does more than one thing. It add hooks, it enqueues styles and scripts, and it deactivates plugins. That suggests it should be broken up into more classes.

Secondly, I never use the singleton pattern. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138012/6077935) for why.

Thirdly, there's no reason for the & before $this. That's a holdover from PHP 4. All object in PHP (that WordPress supports) are now passed by reference so there's no reason to do this. This won't actually cause any side effects, it's just a code smell.

functions.php

```
//* Start bootstrapping the plugin
require __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/plugin.php';

//* Use the plugins_loaded at priority 0 to finish bootstrapping
$plugin = new plugin();
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [ new bootstrap( $plugin ), 'plugins_loaded' ], 0 );
```

bootstrap.php

```
class bootstrap() {
  public $plugin;
  public function __constructor( $plugin ) {
    $this->plugin = $plugin;
  }
  public function plugins_loaded() {
    array_map( function( $hook ) {
      method_exists( $this->plugin, $hook ) && add_action( $hook, [ $this->plugin, $hook ] );
    }, [ 'plugins_loaded', 'after_setup_theme', 'init', 'admin_init', 'wp' ] );
  }
}
```

plugin.php

```
class plugin() {
  public function plugins_loaded() {
    //* Maybe you want to require more files here
    add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'public_init' ] );
  }
  public function plugins_loaded() {
    //* This method fires on plugins_loaded
  }
  //* WordPress doesn't fire a hook on public init
  public function public_init() {
    if( is_admin() ) return;
    //* Add some hooks for the public side
  }
  public function admin_init() {
    //* Add some hooks for the admin side
  }
  public function init() {
    //* Add some hooks for both public and admin side
  }
  //* Etc.
}
```

This is how I structure how to add hooks to plugins and themes. It's not necessarily the best. It's certainly not the only way.